# Add a bootstrap theme to an Aurelia / DotNetCore SPA application

Tags: webpack, asp.net-core, single-page-application, aurelia

I'm fairly new to Aurelia, but I'm trying to set up a sample site using the latest Asp.Net Core and Aurelia (Webpack) from here: https://github.com/EisenbergEffect/aspnetcore-aurelia-build-2017

But I want it to use a bootstrap theme from here: https://adminlte.io/

I found a link (https://thedon.me/2016/02/11/adminlte-with-aurelia/) that has some steps to add this using jspm, but the later versions (referenced in the sample above) is using webpack instead. I managed to add the AdminLTE using npm via Github, but I don't think that's the right approach.

I assume I can copy files from the AdminLTE package directly into my application, but I was hoping I could keep it as a separate module so I can upgrade it easily in the future.

Expect end-result: Above sample DotNetCore SPA site using the AdminLTE theme to display the AdminLTE sample/main page.